# shellscriptのvenv仮想環境でsourceコマンドが使用出来ない

Tags: bash, shell, python-venv

#### やりたい事

コマンド一つでvenvを使用した仮想環境構築～アクティブ化したい。アクティブ化後、利用するフレームワークをインストールする為に`pip install ...`などを実行したい。

#### 実行環境

OS： Windows 11
試した実行方法： VScode上のbashで`sh ./file1.sh myproject`、`bash ./file1.sh myproject`

#### 試した事

file2.shを作成して`source ./file2.sh`で動作したが、file1.shから実行しても期待した動作になりませんでした。

file1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "project/$1"
cd "project/$1" || exit
python -m venv venv

source ./venv/Scripts/activate　　#この行をsource ./file2.shに置き換えてもアクティブにならない
```

file2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

**追記**
以下の様に、`bash --init-file ...`で実行すると動作出来る事を確認しました。
新たに子プロセスを生成して仮想環境をアクティブにしている？のでしょうか。
理由がよく分からない為正しい方法なのか良ければどなたかご教授お願いしたいです。
また、`bash --init-file ...`以降の行が実行されない事が分かりました（親プロセスが終了したため？）。

実行コマンド：`sh ./file.sh project`

file1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "project/$1"
cd "project/$1" || exit
python -m venv venv
cd ../../

bash --init-file <(echo source "./project/$1/venv/Scripts/activate")

echo "success" 　　#親プロセスが終了したため実行されない？
```

Comment: file1.sh の例は実行時に引数を受け取ってディレクトリを作成しているので、`sh ./file1.sh myProject` のように実行する必要があるように見えます。

Comment: @cubick 様、回答ありがとうございます。記載漏れでしたので追記しました。回答内容通りに実行してもアクティブになりませんでした。

Comment: `bash ./file1.sh` とする場合は、新たにプロセスが生成されてしまいます。`source ./file2.sh` と同様に、`source ./file1.sh myProject` とすることでカレントプロセス(シェルプロセス)で設定が行われます。

Comment: OSがなにで、どうやって実行してるんでしょう? というのが書かれてなくて気になりました

Comment: file1.sh のactivateの後ろに実行したいことを書いていきたいのかと思って回答したのですが違いましたか? まさかとは思ったのですが、file1.shを実行して**今の**シェルの環境が変えたいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> また、`bash --init-file ...` 以降の行が実行されない事が分かりました（親プロセスが終了したため？）。

新たに起動した `bash` プロセスが終了してから実行されます。

```bash
$ ./file1.sh project
(venv) user@host:/work/tmp$
(venv) user@host:/work/tmp$ deactivate
user@host:/work/tmp$ exit
exit
success
$
```

質問文にコメントした様に `source ./file1.sh project` で充分ですが、以下の様にしてもよいかと思います。

**file1.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "project/$1"
cd "project/$1" || exit
python3 -m venv venv
cd ../../

exec $SHELL --rcfile /dev/fd/3 3<<EOS
  source ./project/$1/venv/Scripts/activate
  echo "success"
EOS
```

**実行結果**

```bash
$ ./file1.sh project
success
(venv) user@host:/work/tmp$
(venv) user@host:/work/tmp$ deactivate
user@host:/work/tmp$ exit
exit
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source ./file1.sh project
```

でいいですね

---

(以下は残しておきます)
activateする必要を全く感じないです
PATHの先頭にvenv/binを追加するだけでいいのではないですか? (これで何か不都合がありますか?)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "project/$1"
cd "project/$1" || exit
python -m venv venv

export PATH=$(realpath venv/bin):$PATH

# 以降 pip や pythonがvenv配下の実行ファイルを起動するのでその例

python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'↲

pip install pytz
python -c 'import pytz; print(pytz.__file__)'
```